# Overloading the ++ operator for binary trees

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, binary-tree, increment

In my program I have a preOrder Iterator class for my Binary Tree. In it I am trying to implement an operator overload on the ++ operator in order to traverse the tree from beginning to end. But I get confused because a Binary Tree can have both a left and a right side. How do I know where the beginning is? Is it always the left most node?

This is my code structure:

Parent Binary Tree:

```
/* Binary Tree */
class bin_tree
{
public:
    int data;
    bin_tree *left;
    bin_tree *right;
    bin_tree *parent;

    class preOrder_iterator; //child iterator class 
};
```

Child iterator class:

```
/* Iterator class -- inherits from parent */
class bin_tree::preOrder_iterator : public bin_tree
{
        preOrder_iterator& operator ++ () //++ prefix operator overload
        {

        }
        preOrder_iterator begin();
        preOrder_iterator end();
};
```

One I figure out what to use for the beginning and end, how would I implement this overload?

Comment: Is your question "what's the algorithm for getting from a node to its successor node in a binary tree"?

Comment: Kind of, but I have to do it with an operator overload, and I also don't know what to define as the beginning.

Comment: To find the beginning, start at the root. Keep going down the left pointers until you find a node that has no node to the left of it. That's the first node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this node has a right sub-tree, the successor will be the first node in the right sub-tree. So go to the right sub-tree, from there, keep going left until you can go left no more. That node is the successor.

If the node has no right sub-tree, we check its parent. If it has no parent and no right sub-tree, it's the last node in the tree. When we get to the parent, there are two sub cases:

1. We were the left node. In this case, our parent is our successor.
2. We were the right node. In this case, we walk the chain of parent nodes until we either find a node that comes after us or find a node without a parent. In the former case, that node is our successor. In the latter case, we are the last node and have no successor.